# Word to word search in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have generated three different scaffold namely **Education**, **Health**, **Jobs** and all these contain five string each. How should i make a search that can search all these  strings.
For Example: My Education scaffold have a string called PRIMARY SCHOOL,
so if a user searches *Best primary school in New York* it should return with all the results submitted in the PRIMARY SCHOOL string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you try to do multi-table searching in Rails, you are sort of breaking certain ideas behind `ActiveRecord::Base`.

Preferably, you would enforce searching on individual tables.
Then for each model you can create a `search` method.

```
def self.search(query)
  query = "%#{query}%"
  where(
    'column_1 LIKE ?
  OR column_2 LIKE ?
  OR column_3 LIKE ?
  OR column_4 LIKE ?
  OR column_5 LIKE ?',
  query,
  query,
  query,
  query,
  query
  )
end
```

Otherwise, to achieve a multi table search you will need a handwritten query.

I would avoid this at all costs.

```
query = 'PRIMARY SCHOOL'
sql = <<SQL
  SELECT educations.*,
         healths.*,
         jobs.*,
  FROM educations,
       healths,
       jobs
  WHERE (each_table.each_column LIKE "%#{query}%")
SQL

records = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)

records.each do |record|
  # ...
end
```

This is a very unrecommended way of working with SQL in Ruby on Rails.

Comment: Also, I personally use a gem called `squeel` to cleanup some of these queries. With `squeel` you can write `where { (column.like "%#{query}%") | (column2.like "%#{query}%") }`. Which can make code cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for your help @fbelanger ...i want to search a whole column...for example i have a text field called NAME where users fill up there name... what am trying to achieve is when someone searches the word name then he should get the full list of what the users have filled in. Can you please help me with that